# UIImageView's tap gesture not implementing selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

So I have an UIImageView inside a UITableViewCell. Now, I have dealt with something like this before and I have implemented in an identical way. But here's my problem. When I programmatically set a UITapGesureRecongizer to a cells image view, I am not getting any response from my log. Here's what I have tried. I have tried using this code inside of the UITableviewCell class:

**UITableViewCell.m**

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *banner = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(Banner:)];
    self.bannerImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.bannerImageView addGestureRecognizer:banner];

-(void)Banner:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

    NSLog(@"HERE !!!");

}
```

I have also tried using the same code inside my TableViewController. Ideally, I would like to have the code inside this class.

**UITableViewController.m**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *banner = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(Banner:)];
cell.bannerImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
cell.bannerImageView addGestureRecognizer:banner;
-(void)Banner:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

    NSLog(@"HERE !!!");

}
```

Something tells me that I have to change the UIViews hierarchy or 'z-index' for this to work? I am out of ideas. If someone could help that would be great. Thanks

Comment: I added your code to one of my cells with an image view, and it worked fine. Did you check to make sure self.bannerImageView is not nil?

Answer (score 0):

What is likely going on is that your gesture recognizer is conflicting with one of the gesture recognizers installed on the tableview, scrollview, or tableview cell.  Try subscribing as the delegate of the gesture recognizer and implement the method

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

For now just return yes to confirm if this is actually the issue, you can fine tune any resulting issues from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifierName"];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *banner = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(Banner:)];

    [cel.bannerImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [cell.bannerImageView addGestureRecognizer:banner];


    if (cell == nil) {


        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"yourIdentifierName"];

    }

    return cell;
}
-(void)Banner:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

    NSLog(@"HERE !!!");

}
```